# Swap not mounting

Tags: swap

I have just installed SolydX (Debian based) onto a laptop with the following specs:

-Toshiba Tecra A4
-800MHz Centrino CPU
-nVidia 6600 GPU
-512MB RAM

After installing Conky to monitor my system, I noticed that there is no Swap space showing. I made a 2GB Swap partition on install. I have checked the `fstab` file and all looks good (it was populated by the installer).

Most answers I've found so far use the `swapon` command, however when I try these commands, I get a 'command not found' error.

How can I get my system to use the Swap space?

Below is my `fstab` file

```
proc                                        /proc       proc    defaults    0   0
UUID=49f4751f-4ad9-4f3e-baa8-853d3d43153c   /           ext4    rw,errors=remount-ro    0   1 
UUID=b4e77f64-86d7-4a72-888d-fbbcc5d1045c   /home       ext4    rw,errors=remount-ro    0   0
UUID=3b3aec73-825f-4ec0-96c5-f9c79d599f9e   swap        swap    sw  0   0
```

Comment: Are you root when you call `swapon`? `swapon` is in `/sbin`, a path normally only added to root's environment.

Comment: use `blkid` as root (`sudo blkid`) to check that the UUID of your swap partition is the same as the one in `fstab`.

Comment: I do prefix with sudo every time. I have also checked the UUID and they match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GParted, I deleted the swap partition and made a new one. After selecting `swapon`, swap activated and Conky mirrors this in it's display.

Answer (score 2):

You ought to have the `swapon` command.

You would need to be logged in as root to use it; if you are not, then you probably don't have /sbin in your path, so you're not finding it.

Did you try

```
sudo /sbin/swapon -a
```

For the swap not to be used automatically, there's probably a real problem, but that should show you the error.

If you still get 'command not found', something's really wrong with your system—you could maybe try reinstalling the `mount` package.

Comment: Told APT to reinstall mount to see if that fixed it and got an error suggesting I run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a
'. After running that, the 'swapon -a' command now gives an error "swapon: /dev/sda3: swapon failed: Invalid argument". 'swapon -s' shows no swap partition mounted. Using GParted, I selected to make a new UUID, then ran 'sudo /sbin/swapon -U 767cd69b-dc33-4d5d-8d7e-b278d78ba9c8' with the same "Invalid argument" error.

Comment: Just tried GParted's option to turn swap on and got the following "swapon: /dev/sda3: found swap signature: version 1, page-size 4, same byte order
swapon: /dev/sda3: pagesize=4096, swapsize=2147573760, devsize=2147565568
swapon: /dev/sda3: last_page 0x80016000 is larger than actual size of swapspace
swapon: /dev/sda3: swapon failed: Invalid argument"